# How do I install Unix system V?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I got my hands on a copy of Unix system V. I downloaded a software to write img files to floppy disks. But when I try to boot from the floppy on my old 128MB ram computer it says disk image failure.  How do I install Unix and is it even possible?

Comment: why bother?  an ancient unix isn't going to do anything your puppy linux doesn't do.  it wont even make a good learning environment because there's far more tutorials etc available for linux.

Comment: Yeah I know but I just wanted to try it out you know,  wanted to explore.

Comment: If you want something that feels just like an ancient unix, like stepping back in time 30 years, something without all the niceties and frills of a modern linux distribution, then try freebsd.  It feels ancient but is very actively maintained, with lots of online docs and tutorials and forums.

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.livingcomputers.org/Discover/Online-Systems/Request-a-Login.aspx. Also http://minnie.tuhs.org/mailman/listinfo/tuhs could be of interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unix System V is from 1983. There is a pretty good chance that the disk image you have is not even for Intel x86 architectures and won't work at all on your system or emulator, let alone other hardware driver incompatibilities. Maybe if you used one of the alternate qemu architectures. But most likely you'd need to get your hands on compatible hardware that still works. There are some youtube videos where people boot these old systems and explorer them a bit.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a complete tutorial of how installing AT&T System V/386 (SYSVR4 v 2.1) in Bochs on the [www.linuxquestions.org forum](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/other-*nix-55/using-floppies-in-at-and-t-unix-system-v-release-4-version-2-1-or-docs-link-4175428440/). Some paticipants of the forum claim to run it under qemu, VirtualBox and even on an bare bone Pentium 3.

Even if studying System V is a form of computer archeology, it  could still have some historical and technical interest.